# Symfony 5 modificar Form dinámicamente

Tags: php, symfony, twig, doctrine, symfony5

estoy intentando replicar el ejemplo del manual de Sumfony:

https://symfony.com/doc/5.4/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#form-events-submitted-data

Para ello dispongo de 3 entidades.
La primera "Addresses" representa una dirección que dispone como clave foránea la ciudad "Cities" y la provincia "Provinces".

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Addresses
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="Addresses", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="IX_Addresses_AddressTypeId", columns={"AddressTypeId"}), @ORM\Index(name="IX_Addresses_AssociationProcuratorId", columns={"AssociationProcuratorId"}), @ORM\Index(name="IX_Addresses_CityId", columns={"CityId"}), @ORM\Index(name="IX_Addresses_ProvinceId", columns={"ProvinceId"}), @ORM\Index(name="IX_Addresses_WayTypeId", columns={"WayTypeId"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\AddressesRepository")
 */
class Addresses
{
    /**
     * @var binary
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="AddressId", type="binary", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $addressid;

    /**
     * @var \Cities
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Cities")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="CityId", referencedColumnName="CityId")
     * })
     */
    private $cityid;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Door", type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
     */
    private $door;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Floor", type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
     */
    private $floor;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="FullAddress", type="text", length=0, nullable=true)
     */
    private $fulladdress;

    /**
     * @var bool
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="IsPublic", type="boolean", nullable=false)
     */
    private $ispublic;

    /**
     * @var bool
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="IsReceivingMagazine", type="boolean", nullable=false)
     */
    private $isreceivingmagazine;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="MailBox", type="string", length=20, nullable=true)
     */
    private $mailbox;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Stairway", type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
     */
    private $stairway;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="WayName", type="string", length=100, nullable=true)
     */
    private $wayname;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="WayNumber", type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
     */
    private $waynumber;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="ZipCode", type="string", length=14, nullable=true)
     */
    private $zipcode;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="BuildingName", type="string", length=100, nullable=true)
     */
    private $buildingname;

    /**
     * @var \Addresstypes
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Addresstypes")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="AddressTypeId", referencedColumnName="TypeId")
     * })
     */
    private $addresstypeid;

    /**
     * @var \Associationprocurators
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Associationprocurators")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="AssociationProcuratorId", referencedColumnName="AssociationProcuratorId")
     * })
     */
    private $associationprocuratorid;

    /**
     * @var \Provinces
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Provinces")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="ProvinceId", referencedColumnName="ProvinceId")
     * })
     */
    private $provinceid;

    /**
     * @var \Waytypes
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Waytypes")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="WayTypeId", referencedColumnName="TypeId")
     * })
     */
    private $waytypeid;
```

Entidad Provinces

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Provinces
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="Provinces")
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ProvincesRepository")
 */
class Provinces
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="ProvinceId", type="string", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $provinceid;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="ProvinceCode", type="string", length=2, nullable=true)
     */
    private $provincecode;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="ProvinceName", type="string", length=30, nullable=true)
     */
    private $provincename;


    /**
     * @var  ArrayCollection<Cities>
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Cities", mappedBy="provinceid", fetch="LAZY")
    */
    private $cities;
```

Entidad Cities

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Entity\Provinces;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Cities
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="Cities", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="IX_Cities_ProvinceId", columns={"ProvinceId"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\CitiesRepository")
 */
class Cities
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="CityId", type="string", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $cityid;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="CityCode", type="string", length=12, nullable=false)
     */
    private $citycode;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="CityName", type="string", length=30, nullable=false)
     */
    private $cityname;

    /**
     * @var \Provinces
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Provinces", inversedBy="cities")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="ProvinceId", referencedColumnName="ProvinceId")
     * })
     */
    private $provinceid;
```

He creado mi FormType:

```
<?php
namespace App\Entity\Form;
use App\Entity\Addresses;
use App\Entity\Provinces;
use App\Entity\Cities;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;


class AddressFormType extends AbstractType
{


   public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) : void
    {
        $builder
        ->add('provinceid',  EntityType::class, array(
            'class' => Provinces::class,
            'placeholder' => 'Elige uno...',
            
        ))
        ;
        


        $formModifier = function ( FormInterface $form, Provinces $province = null) {
            
            $cities = null === $province ? [] : $province->getCities();
            $form->add('cityid', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => Cities::class,
                'placeholder' => 'Elige uno...',
                'choices'     => $cities,
            ));
        };    


        $builder->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
            function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
                // this would be your entity, i.e. SportMeetup
                $address = $event->getData();
                //var_dump($event->getData());
                $formModifier($event->getForm(), $address->getProvinceid());
            }
        );


        $builder->get('provinceid')->addEventListener(

            FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
            function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
                var_dump($event);
                // It's important here to fetch $event->getForm()->getData(), as
                // $event->getData() will get you the client data (that is, the ID)
                $province = $event->getForm()->getData();

                
                // since we've added the listener to the child, we'll have to pass on
                // the parent to the callback functions!
                $formModifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $province);
            }
        );    






    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Addresses::class,
            'include_published_at' => false,
        ]);
    }
    

}
```

La vista :

```
          {{ form_start(form_address) }}

          {{ form_row(form_address.provinceid) }} 

          {{ form_row(form_address.cityid) }} 

          {{ form_end(form_address) }}


          <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script>
             var $province = $('#address_form_provinceid');
             $province.change(function() {
                var $form = $(this).closest('form');
                var data = {};
                data[$province.attr('name')] = $province.val();
                $.ajax({
                   url : $form.attr('action'),
                   type: $form.attr('method'),
                   data : data,
                   complete: function(html) {
                         $('#address_form_cityid').replaceWith(
                            $(html.responseText).find('#address_form_cityid')
                         );
                   }
                });
             });
          </script>
```

El problema es que en ningún caso se recarga el desplegable de las ciudades. Nunca se llega a ejecutar la función dentro del EventListener del POST_SUBMIT

¿Alguna idea?

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente el problema estaba en el Controller. Todo el código del formulario está correcto. El problema era que faltaba el handler del request:

```
        $address = new Addresses();
        $form_address = $this->createForm(AddressFormType::class, $address);
        $form_address->handleRequest($request);  // Si no hay manejador no captura los EventLister
```